# Difference or Similarities between PCB and PDB

Tags: unix, assembly, process, dos, x86-16

Is the concept of process (PCB or Process Control Block) used in operating systems like, Unix, Linux, windows and concept of process (PDB or Process Data Block)  used in source code of msdos operating system same. I'm very confused in both terms; process  control block (PCB) and process data block (PDB). is the term "process" regarded with both PCB and PDB same.

Comment: Is the term process in PCB and PDB same?

Comment: MS-DOS is a single-tasking operating system. And what you call a "process" in most modern OSs is very much related to scheduling multiple tasks. Therefore I think there is some difference.

Answer (score 2):

In the real world "PCB" means "Process Context Block." That is the data structure that holds the register state of the a process.

In the world of moronically written computer science textbooks designed to confuse students, PCB is a mythical structure that contains everything about a process. I am not aware of any real world, commercial operating system that has such a data structure. None of the Unix systems where I have done operating system development has a Process Control Block and I have never heard of a process control block on MS Windows.

MS-DOS has a process data block but that system is so different from Unix/MS Windows that there is little connection between the two.